# Creation of the tag liblas

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I would like to suggest a creation of the tag 'liblas'.

It is an useful library to work with aerial lidar files. And we have already interesting question about this library. Reference: https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=liblas+is%3Aquestion

**Short definition:** libLAS is a C/C++ library for reading and writing the very common LAS LiDAR format.

**Description**: libLAS is a C/C++ library for reading and writing the very common LAS LiDAR format. The ASPRS LAS format is a sequential binary format used to store data from LiDAR sensors and by LiDAR processing software for data interchange and archival. See Features for more details on what libLAS can provide a LiDAR software developer. See Getting Started with libLAS for how to get started using the library. LibLAS’ initial development was supported in 2007-2008 by the IGSB of the Iowa DNR for use in its state-wide LIDAR project. Ongoing support for libLAS is provided by a number of organizations including the U.S. Army Cold Regions Research and Engineering Laboratory. LibLAS builds upon by Martin Isenburg and Jonathan Shewchuk of LLNL/UC Berkeley in their LAStools project to do a number of things. First, the libLAS focuses almost completely on providing an easy-to-program-with library for software developers wishing to implement the LAS specification in their own software. libLAS is a building block for developers looking to implement their own LiDAR data processing when working with ASPRS LAS data.

More info: http://www.liblas.org/

Comment: Tags are created when they are needed in questions. If you can provide references to questions that deserve this tag, we would be happy to supply it.

Comment: @whuber, I provided the references in the first link above: http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=liblas

Comment: Thanks; I overlooked that was a search here. (+1)

Comment: Since you just need rep>3K for this, I have created the tag, and tagged a few questions with [liblas](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/liblas/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we just need rep>3K for this, I have created the tag, and tagged a few questions with [liblas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liblas)